# Find data within entire key

Tags: file, batch-file, registry

I've been trying without much success to write a reg query to search the entire services key (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services) for values that contain MSISCSI within data.

I can quite easily pull this information if I already know the specific key, for example (just example, no value info)

```
reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\adsi /v dependonservice | findd "msiscsi"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
REG HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services /S /F MSiSCI /D /E
```

Answer (score -1):

#### How do I search `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services` for specific values?

Use the following batch file.

**RegFindValue.cmd:**

```
@echo off 
setlocal
rem loop throught the service keys
for /f "tokens=*" %%k in ('reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services') do (
rem look for the value MSiSCI
  for /f "tokens=*" %%j in ('reg query "%%k" /v dependonservice 2^>nul ^| findstr "MSiSCI"') do (
    echo key: %%k
    echo value: %%j
    )
  )
endlocal
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) - Search for strings in files.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [reg](http://ss64.com/nt/reg.html) - Read, Set or Delete registry keys and values, save and restore from a .REG file.